# iOS -how to Group controls?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development and can't find any good guides on how to build a GUI that isn't just controls on a view. I need to group texts, images and controls in colored areas similar to the picture  in the link below. Especially the brown background with the white area with rounded corners is exactly what I need (the brown frame).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm targeting iOS 5 and higher....

http://www.filemaker.co.uk/products/filemaker-pro/images/whats_new/graphic_ios_ipad_iphone.png

Comment: Have a look at the `frame` property of the `UIView` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make everything as a part of superview..please see the image..[image]

Comment: also, I dont see any image attached but for rounded rect you can put an imageView inside a UIView with bg alpha set to 0..

Comment: Sorry, the img wouldn't upload. Added a link... So as in the FileMaker image, I need several areas with a background color, rounded corners and controls within. The sizes need to change with the content (some texts and images, and controls)

Comment: for the several views, you can create several UIView hierarchies and add different views inside it. by making them IBOutlets you can toggle the frames.

Comment: for resizing of the images, please create a new question because it can be very detailed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Been goofing around with views now and it seems to work fine. I have some problems accessing the nested views, but hopfully I'll work it out...