# How to find similar control of certain type in Xamarin iOS and loop through

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS mobile project I have a screen which has 10 image views.I would like to know if there is a way to loop through all controls in my Xib and find the item of type UIImageView and if there is no image set, then set an image.

All my imageviews are named but I dont want to go through a horrible if- else if check.

Thank you guys.

Comment: instead of looping though all controls to indentify the imageview, if you have all 10 imageView declared in your CS file then you could easily create an array of those imageViews then loop through it and check which imageview has image or not.

Comment: @SahilManchanda - Thanks for your comment, yes it does make sense however my image views are declared in the designer i.e., I have created them via drag and drop in the designer and given them a Name.

Comment: @Abe I think this just can be used in Xcode. .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842820/ios-how-to-group-controls